# Bootstrap: make a container have offsets

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a blog system, how should I position the blog post div so it has those gaps to fit date div?
[image]

[image]

The code I'm using:

```html
<div class="container post">
  <div class="date">
  <h3>20</h3>
  <h5>november</h5>
  </div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

```css
.post{
 margin-top: 40px;
 padding: 10px;
 color: white;
 background: black;
 border: 3px white solid;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 position: relative;
}

.date {
 position: absolute;
    border: 2px white solid;
    width: 55px;
    height: 50px;
    left: -40px;
    background: black;
}

.date h3{
 position: relative;
    top: -18px;
    left: 11px;
}
.date h5{
 position: relative;
    top: -28px;
    left: 2px;
 
 
}
```

Any help with this? I need it so the blog post can fit the div with date.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
.post {
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    border: 3px white solid;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    position: relative;
}

.date {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 2px white solid;        
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

.date h3 {
    position: relative;
}

.date h5 {
    position: relative; 
}
```

This will put the date in the top left of the post container and wrap the text around it.